# How do i use Composer to install a package without a version (only master)

Tags: composer-php

I am new to composer and i am trying to install this following lib via the composer update

```
https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8
```

so as i understand my composer.json looks like this

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "libs/vendor"
    },
    "require": {
        "raven/raven": "0.7.1",
        "monolog/monolog": "1.7.*",
        "smarty/smarty": "3.1.16",
        "forceutf8/forceutf8": "master"
    }
}
```

Bt for some reason (as i think forceutf8 has no version) its halts with error, all the rest installed correctly, error i get is

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package forceutf8/forceutf8 could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package na
me.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

i tried following version also but no luck still

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "libs/vendor"
    },
    "name": "career/skillquest",
    "repositories": [
      {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8"
      }
    ],
    "require": 
      {
        "forceutf8/forceutf8": "dev-master",
        "raven/raven": "0.7.1",
        "monolog/monolog": "1.7.*",
        "smarty/smarty": "3.1.16"
      }
}
```

Issue was it needs to be

```
"neitanod/forceutf8": "dev-master"
```

NOT

```
"forceutf8/forceutf8": "master"
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First of all, you have the wrong name: `forceutf8/forceutf8` Correct name is: `neitanod/forceutf8`

Composer adds a prefix of "dev-" to every branch name that is not looking like a version number, and a suffix "-dev" to branch names that look like version numbers.

Example: Branch "master" is called "dev-master", branch "feature" is called "dev-feature". Branch "1.0.x" is called "1.0.x-dev".

So this part is wrong:

```
"require": {
    "raven/raven": "0.7.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.7.*",
    "smarty/smarty": "3.1.16",
    "forceutf8/forceutf8": "master"
}
```

Correct version would be:

```
"require": {
    "raven/raven": "0.7.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.7.*",
    "smarty/smarty": "3.1.16",
    "neitanod/forceutf8": "dev-master"
}
```

Now requiring branches without tagged versions is not the best thing because these info is quite unstable - any new commit can break things, and it is not that easy to point exactly at the commit you wanted to use. To protect you agains this, Composer by default does not load these development branch, but will only load stable versions. You have to enable loading development versions:

```
"require": {
    "raven/raven": "0.7.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.7.*",
    "smarty/smarty": "3.1.16",
    "neitanod/forceutf8": "dev-master@dev"
}
```

The "@dev" flag allows to load development versions of the version mentioned (which in this case is a branch, but "1.0.0@dev" would work the same way, allowing all (including dev) versions of 1.0.0, like "1.0.0-alpha", but also the stable "1.0.0").

Note that you could also allow development version for ALL your dependencies by using "minimum-stability", but this is not recommended, because it will load development versions for EVERYTHING according to the version requirement. In your case, you would grab the latest dev version of monolog's 1.7 branch only, but this might be enough to bring a once stable software into a broken state.

Comment: but this doenst recognise the git url ?

Comment: I assume that the package is registered on http://packagist.org, but currently that site seems to be down. So you'll have no luck updating anything whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you so, so much for explaining that: 'Composer adds a prefix of "dev-" to every branch name that is not looking like a version number, and a suffix "-dev" to branch names that look like version numbers.' I despise this syntax in Composer.

Answer (score 25):

In *composer.json*:

```
{
    "name": "example/example-app",
    "repositories": [
      {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8"
      }
    ],
    "require": 
      {
        "neitanod/forceutf8": "dev-master",
        "raven/raven": "0.7.1",
        "monolog/monolog": "1.7.*",
        "smarty/smarty": "3.1.16"
      }
}
```

Comment: can you pls add the full json file with other packages, i tried to adding this but failed to get the required file format

Comment: And where is the forceutf8 software?

Comment: Sorry, i'm forgot to add 'forceutf8' in require. Fixed

Comment: tried but still didnt work i get  Problem 1
    - The requested package forceutf8/forceutf8 could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package na
me.

Comment: in _require_ write *"neitanod/forceutf8" : "dev-master"* instead *"forceutf8/forceutf8": "dev-master"*

Answer (score 13):

It's simple! You should type on console:

```
composer require blablabla@thepackage dev-master
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the version name in the composer.json file.
Just find any package which are installable with Composer at : https://packagist.org/

Search the package name there, you will find the version name.
And here is the link for the package you wanted : https://packagist.org/packages/neitanod/forceutf8