# But these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability

Tags: php, composer-php, sparkpost

Hi, I'm getting this problem when I try to install [SparkPost PHP Library](https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost):

> **Problem 1** 
> - The requested package sparkpost/sparkpost No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by sparkpost/sparkpost[No version set (parsed
> as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or
> minimum-stability.

It appears when I try to execute this command:
`composer require sparkpost/sparkpost`

---

Full Console Output:

```json
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
Using version ^2.0 for sparkpost/sparkpost
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package sparkpost/sparkpost No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by sparkpost/sparkpost[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Composer File:

```json
{
  "name": "sparkpost/sparkpost",
  "description": "Client library for interfacing with the SparkPost API.",
  "license": "Apache 2.0",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "SparkPost"
    }
  ],
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": "post-install.sh",
    "post-update-cmd": "post-install.sh",
    "test": "./vendor/bin/phpunit",
    "fix-style": "php-cs-fixer fix ."
  },
  "require": {
    "php": "^5.6 || ^7.0",
    "php-http/httplug": "^1.0",
    "php-http/message": "^1.0",
    "php-http/client-implementation": "^1.0",
    "php-http/discovery": "^1.0",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.8 || ^5.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^0.9.4",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^1.11",
    "nyholm/nsa": "^1.0",
    "satooshi/php-coveralls": "dev-master",
    "phpunit/phpcov": "2.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "SparkPost\\": "lib/SparkPost"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "SparkPost\\Test\\": "test/unit"
    }
  }
}
```

Any solution?

---

PD: I've tried to set `"minimum-stability": "stable"` to `"dev"`, but I have the same error

Comment: How does your `composer.json` look like?

Comment: @Martin is in the question, where I wrote Composer File

Comment: That looks like `composer.json` for `sparkpost/sparkpost`

Comment: @But that's the problem. When I require sparkpost/sparkpost it crashes and stops the command. Also when I try to use composer install

Comment: I wanted to see **your** `composer.json`, not `composer.json` for `sparkpost/sparkpost`. I can find that one on github. The problem is most likely on your side.

Comment: @Martin There is not any other file. The unique file that is requested is that

Comment: Did you try to add requirements' requirement in the composer.json with needed version to bypass the error?

Comment: Finally I solved by using a VPS opening the required ports and not using composer @zennin

Answer (score 6):

You can define it in `composer.json` as:

```
"some-vendor/some-library": "@dev"
```

That should overrule the stability-setting.

Answer (score 0):

If your project doesn't have version, you should specify require the development version, e.g.:

```
composer require sparkpost/sparkpost --dev
```

or:

```
composer require sparkpost/sparkpost:dev-master
```

You can specify the `version` in your `composer.json`, then create a tag for that release (`git tag`).

See also: [How do i use Composer to install a package without a version (only master)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21694497/55075)

Comment: Note that the `--dev` flag is used to  add requirement to require-dev. It will not include the development version. The second example is the correct one.