# How to solve Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, json, composer-php

Downloaded code from 
https://github.com/cmfcmf/OpenWeatherMap-PHP-Api

I am following instructions that mention in the `README file`.  I have run these following command.

```
composer require "cmfcmf/openweathermap-php-api"
Using version ^2.2 for cmfcmf/openweathermap-php-api
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

> Problem 1
>   - The requested package cmfcmf/openweathermap-php-api No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by cmfcmf/openweathermap-php-api[No
>   version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your
>   requirements or minimum-stability.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

EDIT 
Composer.json file.

https://github.com/cmfcmf/OpenWeatherMap-PHP-Api/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: post your composer.json

Comment: There is an issue with composer.json configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [But these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453388/but-these-conflict-with-your-requirements-or-minimum-stability)